# Handling multiple client requests on multiple instances of a single servers C++

Tags: sockets, client-server

I have an ecosystem in which there is a C++ socket based (TCP/IP) Server. multiple clients can connect to this server. However there are multiple instances of this server running across different physical IP addresses.
Each client has a configuration file which has its client_identification_id and the server address(there is a fallback mechanism in which the client can connect to another server if the primary can't be connected) to connect to, the servers also have a list of registered clients (saved in db). if a client session is already in progress, connection from that client should not be accepted by any of the other servers while the client session is active
I am faced with the problem with below scenario.
3 clients: C1, C2, C3
3 servers: IPS1, IPS2, IPS3

A scenario arises in which C1 could simultaneously connect to IPS1 and IPS2. Since the instances are running on different physical machines, how should i synchronize client request to multiple servers?

Comment: Use a load balancer with session stickiness.

Comment: @EJP i think what you are talking about is the setting in tomcat. My application is written in C++.  Also apart from client connections, there are other services which send the packet to the server using the same client_identification_id as the packet received from client.